# Изменение категории свойства

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

Делаю свой CastomControl и соответственно добавляю свои свойства. по умолчанию они добавляется в "Разное". Собственно вопрос в том, как например перенести его в "Кисть" или создать свою категорию в редакторе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
[Category("Layout")]
public int Parrots { ... }
```

Не забудьте добавить пространство имён `System.ComponentModel`.

Comment: Спасибо. Пробовал делать это так же, но не работало. Заметил что не добавил пространство имен System.ComponentModel

Comment: Пожалуйста! Добавлю вашу информацию в ответ.